# Multiple nullValues in spark csv

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I have a csv file with "" (empty value) and "N/A" and "-" all in the same files. I want them all to be read into the dataframe as nulls. I know that there is an option in spark-csv "nullValue" , which allows me to treat one single string as null. But for me, that is not sufficient for obvious reasons.

There is a pending issue from spark, 
https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/333

which is still open. I was wondering about the most elegent way to get around the problem.

Comment: Is it critical that they be "read in" as Nulls or is it acceptable to read them into the dataframe (say as strings) and then convert to Nulls?

Comment: most elegant solution would be to use a `replaceAll` and make your data uniform.

Comment: @combinatorist , I want to read that against a schema and use it as a dataset. So certain fields that are integers by default contains values like "N/A" or "-" all of which I want to be parsed as null to be able to read into the interger field of my schema case class. So I'd prefer to do it when being read from the file into a dataset tself.

Comment: @philantrovert . I would do it as the last case. But Ideally, I want spark to handle the whole thing rather than a regular in memory replaceAll.

Comment: @VishnuPrathish, what if you read the field into a dataframe as a string, make Null replacements there, convert the field to an int, and then cast that dataframe as a dataset?

Comment: @combinatorist, that works. A slightly modified version of that is also my current solution. I had to rewrite our library method which reads a csv directly into a dataset to make it work that way. The modification is that it accepts any func: String => String as a preprocessor on each row. So that it still runs on each executer. It is also better than the replaceAll solution.

Comment: @VishnuPrathish, great. I translated it into an answer. Please consider upvoting. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reposted from my comment:

- Read the field into a dataframe as a string
- make Null replacements there
- convert the field to an int
- then cast that dataframe as a dataset

Answer (score 0):

For those who cant get it to work on databricks community edition notebook, You probably haven't mentioned the filename.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).